# azure alerts parse library c#

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions

i'm assigned a task to parse azure alerts and extract relevant information from azure alerts. Is there any nuget package which parses azure alerts and extracts resource group/subscription/resource name and alert details ?
Here is sample alert format

{
"schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
"data": {
"essentials": {
"alertId": "/subscriptions/63b6a1c5-3552-4676-8073-c31e2641f787/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/7cf70adc-c221-467c-bcfe-bab9e33d98b2",
"alertRule": "AlertMetricCPUPercentage",
"severity": "Sev0",
"signalType": "Metric",
"monitorCondition": "Fired",
"monitoringService": "Platform",
"alertTargetIDs": [
"/subscriptions/63b6a1c5-3552-4676-8073-c31e2641f787/resourcegroups/bridge/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm01"
],
"configurationItems": [
"vm01"
],
"originAlertId": "63b6a1c5-3552-4676-8073-c31e2641f787_microsoft.insights_metricalerts_AlertMetricCPUPercentage_-1419778843",
"firedDateTime": "2021-05-21T18:20:57.1495223Z",
"description": "if CPU % is less than 10%",
"essentialsVersion": "1.0",
"alertContextVersion": "1.0"
},
"alertContext": {
"properties": null,
"conditionType": "MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria",
"condition": {
"windowSize": "PT5M",
"allOf": [
{
"metricName": "Percentage CPU",
"metricNamespace": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"operator": "LessThan",
"threshold": "10",
"timeAggregation": "Maximum",
"dimensions": [],
"metricValue": 0.95,
"webTestName": null
}
],
"windowStartTime": "2021-05-21T18:12:44.375Z",
"windowEndTime": "2021-05-21T18:17:44.375Z"
}
}
}
}

Comment: It’s just a json,  you can use JSON.net

Answer (score 1):

As stated above it's just JSON data so you'll just want to create a C# class mapped to the properties you're interested in and then deserialize the data to an object of that class.

Here is a snippet from the Microsoft docs on deserializing JSON data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace DeserializeExtra
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string SummaryField;
        public IList<DateTimeOffset> DatesAvailable { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, HighLowTemps> TemperatureRanges { get; set; }
        public string[] SummaryWords { get; set; }
    }

    public class HighLowTemps
    {
        public int High { get; set; }
        public int Low { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string jsonString =
@"{
  ""Date"": ""2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00"",
  ""TemperatureCelsius"": 25,
  ""Summary"": ""Hot"",
  ""DatesAvailable"": [
    ""2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00"",
    ""2019-08-02T00:00:00-07:00""
  ],
  ""TemperatureRanges"": {
                ""Cold"": {
                    ""High"": 20,
      ""Low"": -10
                },
    ""Hot"": {
                    ""High"": 60,
      ""Low"": 20
    }
            },
  ""SummaryWords"": [
    ""Cool"",
    ""Windy"",
    ""Humid""
  ]
}
";
                
            WeatherForecast weatherForecast = 
                JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString);

            Console.WriteLine($"Date: {weatherForecast.Date}");
            Console.WriteLine($"TemperatureCelsius: {weatherForecast.TemperatureCelsius}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Summary: {weatherForecast.Summary}");
        }
    }
}
// output:
//Date: 8/1/2019 12:00:00 AM -07:00
//TemperatureCelsius: 25
//Summary: Hot
```

And here is the actual article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0